# Really simple SQL query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am matching texts to keywords. I need to return all texts that contain 2 keywords (4) and (7):

```
TextID  KeywordID
2   4
2   7
3   4
4   4
5   4
5   7
6   4
6   7
7   4
7   7
8   4
9   4
10  4
10  7
11  4
12  4
```

The problem is how to exclude texts that do not contain both like Text IDs 3,4,8,9,11 (they should not be in the results)?

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't have duplicate `textId-KeywordId` pairs, below should work:

```
SELECT textid
FROM table
WHERE keywordId in (4,7)
GROUP BY textid
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 2
```

If you have dups, you can use `count(distinct keywordId)` as per @Gordon's answer.

**Update**
Here's MS Access query:

```
SELECT tblPerformanceKeyword.TextID
FROM tblPerformanceKeyword 
WHERE tblPerformanceKeyword.KeywordID = 4 Or tblPerformanceKeyword.KeywordID = 7
GROUP BY tblPerformanceKeyword.TextID
HAVING COUNT(tblPerformanceKeyword.KeywordID) >= 2;
```

Comment: Agreed, that's why I specified this scenario before my answer. Anyway, will add that bit, thanks.

Comment: Many thanks indeed for your replies! Unfortunately, I am using MSAccess, so could you please tell me the exact syntax based on the above solutions? Here's how it looks originally:SELECT tblPerformanceKeyword.PerformanceKeywordID, tblPerformanceKeyword.TextID, tblPerformanceKeyword.KeywordID
FROM tblPerformanceKeyword
WHERE (((tblPerformanceKeyword.KeywordID)=4 Or (tblPerformanceKeyword.KeywordID)=7));

Comment: @Falkor added MS Access query

Comment: That's perfect! Thanks Darshan... TextID
2
5
6
7
10

Answer (score 2):

One method uses `group by` and `having`:

```
select textid
from t
where keywordid in (4, 7)
group by textid
having count(*) = 2;
```

Use `count(distinct keywordid)` if the table can have duplicates.